# Using Weakly Linked Framework's extern constants Crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm attempting to use a Cocoa framework inside a plugin (NSBundle) as a weakly-linked framework, so that I can use it in multiple plugins. I have the source for the framework, and have used the framework successfully in another plugin, albeit not as a weakly linked framework. In that case it works well.

It works, but when I attempt to use an extern *const property when configuring aspects of the framework from within my code, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
```

An example of the constant as declared in the framework:

```
Class.h

extern NSString * const AConstant;
```

And the implementation:

```
Class.m

NSString *const AConstant = @"someString";
```

Code within my app that causes the error:

```
NSLog(@"%@", AConstant);
```

The framework is loading - if I do not attempt to use the constants it works as expected. I can also configure it by using the value of the constants manually, i.e.

```
[framework setConfig:@"someString"]
```

Instead of what I'd prefer to use:

```
[framework setConfig:AConstant]
```

As alluded to above, I am able to modify the framework if necessary.

Does anyone have any tips on what I could do to get this framework running as a weak_framework?

Comment: @Costique: right, thanks. Typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your framework issue, but you could work around your problem by declaring the string only in the header files, like this:

```
__unused static NSString *const AConstant = @"someString";
```

The `__unused` keyword stops the compiler warning that the constant is not used by every file that includes the header. The only problem being that you'll have to use proper `[string isEqual: AConstant]` comparisons, pointer comparisons won't work.

Comment: Currently I'm working around it by using the constant value directly: `[framework setConfig:@"someString"]`. I will wait a while longer, and if no "framework fix" answer appears, shall accept & use yours. Thanks!