# Can NSString constants be weak linked?

Tags: ios

Can NSString constants be weak linked?  `AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540` isn't defined prior to iOS 5. I avoid actually referencing it and it loads fine in gdb, but when I load an ipa, it seems to crash in dyld before ever invoking main.

The related question, [Using Weakly Linked Framework's extern constants Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274088/using-weakly-linked-frameworks-extern-constants-crash), seems to say "no" and I've taken the same apporoach: using the string value directly.

Comment: It may be unrelated, but I found that the linker behaves differently in regards to weak-linked symbols when building for an .ipa archive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10265140/19679 . I had to tell users of my framework to explicitly weak link the Core Video framework to prevent crashes in ad hoc or App Store builds.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I've found since posting as well. Only archived ipa's fail and making the framework Optional gets around the error.

Comment: It's high on my to-do list for WWDC to track down the engineers and see whether this is a bug or I'm just missing something about that part of the build process.

Answer (score 6):

Constants can be weak linked too. To test if the constant is available you must check if it’s address is not `NULL` before you try to use it:

```
if (&AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540 != NULL) {
     // Constant is available and can be used
}
```

Note the `&` operator to take the address of the constant.