# App crashes when using a symbol from a later OS X release

Tags: macos

I have this piece of code running on OS X 10.7:

```
NSLog(@"Start");
if (NSAccessibilityPriorityKey != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"%p", NSAccessibilityPriorityKey);
}
NSLog(@"End");
```

The code crashes (`SIGSEGV`) after the `Start` marker and before it gets to the `End` marker. According to the headers, the `NSAccessibilityPriorityKey` symbol was introduced in 10.9:

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSAccessibilityPriorityKey NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
```

My deployment target is set to 10.6, so I thought the code should run, just the symbol might be `NULL`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have to use the `&` operator when checking for weakly linked strings:

```
if (&NSAccessibilityPriorityKey != NULL) { … }
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837418/can-nsstring-constants-be-weak-linked).